# Install Sierra without a recovery partition?

Tags: install, macos, recovery-hd

How can I install macOS Sierra without a recovery partition?

I am installing into a virtual machine, and will make manual backups of the VM. I do no need or want the extra 5 gigs of the recovery partition and its copy of the Sierra installer app.

Comment: The Recovery HD is only ~650 MB and can actually be needed for some things, so I'd not remove it, even in a VM. What version OS is on the Host? What virtualization software, manufacture and version, are you using and is this a new VM or upgrading an existing OS X VM?

Comment: Under certain circumstances the RHD in the VM is the fastest way to repair your VM's main volume. Else: you would have to create a 2nd VM and attach the hdd of the first VM to repair it. If the VM's main volume is filevaulted the RHD is mandatory.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for mentioning the size of only 2/3 gig. I realized my problem is the  bootable installer volume stored in a `OS X image file.hdd` file (5 gigs) created by Parallels as part of installing Sierra. I mistook that for the recovery partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install Sierra and a Recovery partition is created, I suppose you could just delete the Recovery partition and expand the Sierra partition to include the freed space. The easiest way to delete a partition is with then third party command [gdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/). The freed space can be recovered by using the `diskutil` command.